# how to stop the update funtion calling once per frame

Tags: c#, api, vuforia

I want the script to call the marker only once. Not spamming the console.

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StateManager sm = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager();
        IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> tbs = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours();
        foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in tbs)
        {
            string name = tb.TrackableName;
            Debug.Log("call update " + name);

            targetname.GetComponent<Text>().text = name;


            if (name == markerName)
            {
                detail.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                logoImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                detail.GetComponent<Text>().text =Data + "\n" + stringB;
                StartCoroutine(LoadSpriteImageFromUrl(photo));

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

this is my code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any knowledge regarding Vuforia but the behaviour you are describing is pretty easy to achieve.

Let's call the code that should be run only once the initialization code.
You could then create a separate method that executes only this code. To make sure to only execute this once you can use a flag to check whether it has been executed or not. Then put a simple logic into your update method: If the initialization code has not been execute do so, if it has been executed skip it.

```
public class ContainingClass
{
    public static bool InitRun = false;

    public void Init() //Executed once on the first update call
    {
  
    }

    public void Update() //Executed on every frame
    {
        if(!InitRun)
        {
            Init(); //Call intialization code
            InitRun = true; //set flag that initialization has been run
        }
    }
}
```

This at least should provide a suitable solution for the bevahiour your described.

I also recommend to search for built-in intialization features in the framework as it should provide these.